# How to move specific key value inside another array object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have array object `obj` how to move particular key value `store` inside another array `items` in javascript.
I would like to know how to pass particular key value inside another array in javascript

```
var obj = [
  {
   id:1,
   store: "10",
   items: [{name:"sample1", total: 20}, {name:"sample2", total: 10}] // add store
  },
  {
   id:1,
   store: "11",
   items: [{name:"sample3", total: 10}, {name:"sample4", total: 10}] // add store
  }
]

function newarray(obj){
 return obj.map(e=>...e,e.items.map(i=>{...i,store: e.store })
}
```

Expected Output

```
[
  {
   id:1,
   store: "10",
   items: [{name:"sample1", total: 20, store: "10"}, {name:"sample2", total: 10, store: "10"}]
  },
  {
   id:1,
   store: "11",
   items: [{name:"sample3", total: 10, store: "11"}, {name:"sample4", total: 10, store: "11"}] 
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost in the right direction, just few changes need to be done in your `map` function to get expected output:

```js
var obj = [ { id:1, store: "10", items: [{name:"sample1", total: 20}, {name:"sample2", total: 10}] }, { id:1, store: "11", items: [{name:"sample3", total: 10}, {name:"sample4", total: 10}] }];

var result = obj.map(val=>(val.items = val.items.map(p=>({...p,store:val.store})), val));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` and `forech` if you want to try a different approach

```js
var obj = [
  {
   id:1,
   store: "10",
   items: [{name:"sample1", total: 20}, {name:"sample2", total: 10}] 
  },
  {
   id:1,
   store: "11",
   items: [{name:"sample3", total: 10}, {name:"sample4", total: 10}] 
  }
]
newob=obj.reduce((acc,curr)=>{
  curr.items.forEach(x=>{
   x.store=curr.store
  })
   return [...acc,{...curr}]
},[])
console.log(newob)
```